# Running meteor.js application on your own server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to run my meteor application on my local network so that when I am off-line I can still use the application on any devices connected to my network. I have been following http://ox86.tumblr.com/post/45184656062/running-your-meteor-js-application-on-your-own-server as a basic tutorial on how to do this. I am new to mongodb and node.js, which causes some trouble. However it seems that everything is working except I do not know where my app is running or what the address is? For example after I complete step 4 from the tutorial

```
export PORT=8080
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://bill:123456@localhost:27017/dbName
```

after navigating inside my bundle where main.js is I use

```
forever start main.js
```

There are no errors, but I don't know where my app is or if it is even working. Once again I am new to this idea of hosting my own meteor app. Any ideas or suggestions of what I am doing wrong. Also an explanation of the process would be much appreciated. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you have errors. You should check with `forever logs main.js` to see what you get.

From what it looks like you may have missed the `ROOT_URL` variable too.

```
export ROOT_URL=http://www.yoururl.com
export PORT=8080
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://bill:123456@localhost:27017/dbName
forever start main.js
```

The best check would be to see what you get in the forever logs. Also you may have to install fibers (before you start your app) if you have some error in your logs like *invalid ELF header*

```
cd bundle/programs/server/node_modules
rm -r fibers
npm install fibers@1.0.1
```

Comment: To stop a script easily by its name (instead of its PID), it is better to use `forever start --append --uid "myApplicationName" main.js`, and then `forever stop myApplicationName`

Comment: I've scripted out something similar in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767792/can-you-run-a-meteor-bundle-example-tar-z-on-a-computer-that-doesnt-have-met/23768310