# Can you run a meteor bundle, example.tar.z , on a computer that doesn't have meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor

If I bundle a meteor app using

```
meteor bundle iron.tar.gz
```

can I run the app locally, (localhost:3000), on a different computer that does not have meteor installed. If so, how would I go about doing it? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor pieces will be bundled in your meteor bundle, but you're going to need to have Node.js and NPM installed on that other box.  I use [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) so that it stays up and running and have two scripts.  This one takes the bundle name as an argument and installs the bundle per Meteor's [instructions](http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying) into a directory forever can use:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -d "$1" ]
then
   rm -rf $1
fi

mkdir $1
cp ~/$1.tgz ./$1
cd ./$1

tar xvfz $1.tgz

rm -rf bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/
npm install fibers@1.0.1
```

And then I can run the next script that will take the project name as an input and start it in forever against a MongoDB replica set:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PORT=3000
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://id:pwd@replica1.yourcompany.com:27017,replica2.yourcompany.com:27017,replica3.yourcompany.com:27017/meteor
forever start $1/bundle/main.js
```

After you run that script you can launch it off localhost or setup nginx as an HTTP server that can they proxy it and run on your host over port 80/443.

Comment: That seems more complex than I expected. The situation is that I am sending my meteor app to someone offline who has very little programming knowledge. This person receiving the app only wants to run it locally on their own machine. It makes sense that node.js and a mongodb are needed but can it be simplified or somehow embedded in the .tar.gz bundle?

Comment: AFIAK, that's not possible. It's a tgz is all. You still need to have your end user install node/mongo and then do then run scripts above. Just wondering, why wouldn't you just host it for them especially if they're not savvy in these sorts of things. You can just deploy to Meteor directly. `meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com`

Comment: It's for a network that is not online. The idea is that I can come in and install it quickly and effectively. Is the script above for mac os x?

Comment: I see. Yes, the above script will work on Mac too. I use that as my main OS. At least with the two scripts you can have a command line way of doing those steps you'd otherwise have to do manually. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I was able to successfully do it with the simple hello world meteor application, however when packages are added it seems to complicate things.

Comment: Hey, so I was able to run the bundled version on a mac. However now I want to run it on a windows computer. How do I export the `PORT` and sent the `MONGO_URL` in windows??

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. My goal was to be able to run my meteor app on a computer that did not have meteor, but did have mongodb and node.js. This is a simple step by step procedure. I wanted to run it on a network that was not online and chose the default localhost:3000 as my address.

Step 1:
Navigate to  folder where meteor project is located using terminal (cd location).

Step 2:
In terminal:
`$ export ROOT_URL='http://localhost:3000'`

Step 3:
In terminal:
`$ meteor bundle app.tgz`

Now with this app.tgz you can send it to the other computer that does not have meteor installed, but does have node.js and mongodb.

Step 4:
In finder:
Find the zipped bundled app and unzip it.

Step 5:
Run mongodb in a new terminal:
`$ mongod`

Step 6:
Navigate to the unzipped bundled app in the terminal and use (You must have Node.js installed):
`$ PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/app node main.js`

Step 7:
Navigate Browser to `http://localhost:3000` and app should now be running.

Comment: You're still going to need to delete and install the fibers package, otherwise, AFAIK, the app won't run. See http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying.

Comment: @occasl When it says in the doc's, it only works on the platform that the bundle was created on, does that mean that it will only work on the OS or the actual machine?

Comment: Right, unless you remove/install fibers on the destination host.  At least that's been my experience and thusly why I created the scripts below to just run a few commands to quickly deploy and start my app.